# Python Django admin getting error while deleteing class Question

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a class Question and I registered them to Django admin. And when I want to delete some of them, I am getting an error "OperationalError at /admin/f/question/10/delete/
no such column: f_answer.date".
here is my models.py file content

```
from django.db import models

# ---------- Question ----------

class Question(models.Model):
    ''' Questions '''

    author     = models.CharField('Author', max_length=45)
    title      = models.CharField('Title', max_length=300)
    body       = models.TextField('Body')
    date       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
        verbose_name        = 'Question'
```

Comment: The standar thing to do when something goes wrong with database migrations, is to either do `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` or just drop the database

Comment: that manage.py migrate --run-syncdb command doesn't helped me :(

Comment: I think you added ```date``` field after migration and putting some data in the database, that's why it is giving you the error, you have to drop this database or sync the database

Comment: but how can i drop it ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you show regarding class `Question` does not have any issues with it in its current state. Did you happen to create the Question object across multiple migrations? If you originally had a field, migrated, then removed it -- this could cause issues when attempting to make a transaction.

I am a little skeptical of your date field, since it's both `db_index=true` and allows `null`. It's saying `f_answer.date` is missing... should we interpret that as you having a class `Answer` that is related to the `Question` object? If you have that relationship set with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, but the instance of Question has a `null` value, then Django may be attempting to find related `Answer` objects that do not exist.

Comment: I removed that db_indexa and null arguments, but it is still not working

Comment: Could you update your question with the code for class Answer?

Comment: what class answer?

Comment: So you don't have an ```Answer``` class? Why is the error message stating a ```f_answer```? Are you creating a variable ```f_answer``` in an admin view?

Comment: yes I have class Answer but I didn't tell you about that

Comment: It may be helpful. Could you also provide the code you wrote to register ```Question``` to admin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219209/discussion-between-some-see-a-pen-i-see-a-harpoon-and-alec).